# How do I add ion-avatar on top of ion-card? like the image below

Tags: css, ionic2

I am new to Ionic. I am trying to create ion card for profile page like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CazD.jpg) Basically, I want ion-avatar on top of the ion-card as shown in the [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzAxE.jpg)

How do  I do that?

Below is the code:

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
  // margin-top: auto;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding-top: 200px;
}

#profile-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: -95px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

#profile-image {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<ion-content has-header="true">
  <ion-card id="content">
    <ion-avatar id="profile-info">
      <img id="profile-image" src="img/bg.jpg">
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Show some code, what have you done so far?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto Edited the question. Added code. So far I am able to get the avatar on ion-card but only half but not full round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just missing some CSS parameters for the `#content` element:

```
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
margin-top: 100px;
```

**Demo:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfydwsyq/1/)

Comment: @GabrielBarreto Thanks for the ans. I realised it later that its bcz of the css parameters missing.   I still have one concern; This is manually set CSS. so when I checked it on IOS, the position of avatar and card components changed completely. Do you know a way to set so that they don't change on different device and look same or responsive.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot or reproduce with the fiddle?  When I shrink the above fiddle down to a narrow size it still stays centered and positioned properly.